# Using VLOOKUP to retrieve data in separate sheet based on value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016, vlookup

I have long account codes separated by dashes so they look like ##### - ### - ## - ######. One of these dashes that separate the numbers is a departmental code. In my workbook I have a sheet called "dept_list" and in column E of that sheet I have a formula that derives the department code, in columns F & G, I have the account code & it's description.

The list of account codes is very long so in order to save time, I have a sheet called "lookup" where the user can look up codes based on the department code. So, for example, if the account code the user is looking for has a department code '123' inside of it, they can type '123' in cell B2 on the 'lookup' sheet and click a 'search' button next to the cell which takes them to a separate sheet called 'deptlookup' which will list all of the account codes that have the dept code '123' inside of it, as well as the account description.

I think a VLOOKUP might work for this. I'm just not sure how to set it up syntactically or if I have to do this in VBA. I've never done this before so, if anyone can give me any solid suggestions or advice on the best way to go about doing this, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

This is just two rows of the "dept_list" sheet. Column A is the list of dept codes, Column B is the dept description. Column E is a formula "=MID(F cell,9,3)" which derives the dept code embedded in the full account code and column F is the account code and G is the account description. [image]

This is the search row in sheet "lookup". In cell B2 is where I'd like the user to enter a dept code like '000' or '001' or '002', etc. and click the "search" button.

[image]

After clicking the "search" button the user will be taken to a sheet called "deptlookup" where I'd like all of the full account codes and the account description that contain the dept code that was searched for to be listed here. The reason the description has a #N/A is because I have a VLOOKUP in those cells to pull the description based on the account code populated in Column A.

[image]

I have tried to use a VLOOKUP based on the lookup sheets search parameter cell. I am essentially trying to say: IF the value in lookup sheet cell B2 = MID(Column A of sheet acct_codes,9,3), use VLOOKUP to pull all of those account codes that match that dept code,  if not then return nothing.

```
=IF(lookup!B2=MID(acct_codes!A:A,9,3),VLOOKUP(A2, acct_codes!$A:$A,1,FALSE), " ")
```

I also tried this but it still doesn't work:

```
=IF(lookup!B2=MID(acct_codes!A:A,9,3),VLOOKUP(acct_codes!A:A=MID(acct_codes!A:A,9,3),acct_codes!A:A,1,FALSE), "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample of vlookup with wildcards:

```
=VLOOKUP("*" & D1 & "*",F1:G4,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Here is an example of getting multiple returns.  Say we start with:

[image]

In **C1** we enter:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"123"},A1))>0,1,"")
```

and in **C2**:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"123"},A2))>0,1+MAX($C$1:C1),"")
```

and copy down.  Column **C** marks each row containing *123*
Then in **D1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(ROW(),C:C,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Would D1 in your example be similar to the cell B2 in my lookup sheet?

Comment: Yes, it's the value to be found in the interior of the account codes.  The only wrinkle here is that a VLOOKUP() will only return the first value it finds corresponding to the lookup value.  It sounded like you want to provide your users with a list of multiple account codes - every one that contains "123" in this example.  Is that right?

Comment: @Bandersnatch Yes, that is right. I would like to return all of the account codes that have a particular department code that the user is searching for

Comment: @anve  We can use a **cascading** match & index approach......check back later today

Comment: @Gary'sStudent great! Sounds good. Thanks so much

Comment: @anve  See my **EDIT**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks for your edit. I have just two questions/concerns. the department code, like '123', are always located in the middle of the account codes. I get the department codes with this formula '=MID(cell,9,3)'. Also, I have many department codes, roughly 165 dept codes. I see in C2, you have hard-coded the value '123' as a dept code. Is there a way to avoid that? I have a list of all the dept codes, could I just reference that list rather than hard-coding it? Thanks again!

Comment: @anve  You can place the department code in some cell, say **Z100**, then modify my formulas to reference that cell.............then to change departments, just change a single cell rather than all the formulas.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I added those formulas and it doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps I didn't do a good enough job of explaining. Could I use your Z100 example as my **B2** search cell? I have updated my question with more images to better explain what I'd like, if that helps. Thanks again for your help thus far.

Comment: @anve  I will look at this later today.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I made an edit to the bottom of my question. I took a stab at using a VLOOKUP to get the account codes associated with the dept code that is being used a search parameter. It isn't working as I'd like but I was hoping you could give me some hints or guidance on the correct syntax in order to get it working.